# XSL testing empty strings with <xsl:if> and sorting

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I am having trouble with a template that has to check 3 different nodes and if they are not empty, print the data

I am using `<xsl:if test="string-length(node) != 0">` for each node then doing the output but it is not printing anything.  It is like the test returns zero.

I have selected the parent node of each node I want to check the length on as the template match but it still doesn't work.

Another thing, how do I sort the list using `<datefrom>`.  I tried using this but I get an error about loading the stylesheet.  If I take out the sort it works

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="hoo" match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Registered Festival Organisers and Festivals</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="userfestival.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Registered Festival Organisers and Festivals</h1>
                <h3>Ordered by the festival date ascending</h3>                 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="folktask/member"/>

                <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                    <div class="count"><h2>Total number of festival organisers: <xsl:value-of select="count(/folktask/member/user/account/userlevel[text()=3])"/></h2></div>
                    <div class="count"><h2>Total number of festivals: <xsl:value-of select="count(/folktask/member/festival)"/></h2></div>
                </xsl:if>               
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="folktask/member">
    <xsl:if test="user/account/userlevel='3'">
        <xsl:sort select="festival/event/datefrom"/>
        <div class="userdiv">   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="user"/>    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="festival"/>    
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="user">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="userid"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/address1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/city"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/county"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/postcode"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/telephone"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/mobile"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal/email"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="personal"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="account/username"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="account"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="festival">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="festid"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/eventname"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/url"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/datefrom"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/dateto"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/location"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/eventpostcode"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/coords/lat"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/coords/lng"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/conname"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/conaddress1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/conaddress2"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/concity"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/concounty"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/conpostcode"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contact/conemail"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@id" mode="userid">
        <div class="heading bold"><h2>USER ID: <xsl:value-of select="." /></h2></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/name">
        <div class="small bold">NAME:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/address1">
        <div class="small bold">ADDRESS:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/city">
        <div class="small bold">CITY:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/county">
        <div class="small bold">COUNTY:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/postcode">
        <div class="small bold">POSTCODE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/telephone">
        <div class="small bold">TELEPHONE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/mobile">
        <div class="small bold">MOBILE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal/email">
        <div class="small bold">EMAIL:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:text>mailto:</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal">
        <div class="small bold">SEX:</div>
        <div class="colored bold">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="sex='Male'">
                    <div class="sex male"><xsl:value-of select="sex/."/></div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <div class="sex female"><xsl:value-of select="sex/."/></div>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="account/username">
        <div class="small bold">USERNAME:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="account">
        <div class="small bold">ACCOUNT TYPE:</div>
        <div class="colored ">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="userlevel='1'">
                    <div class="nml bold">Normal User</div>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="userlevel='2'">
                    <div class="vol bold">Volunteer</div>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="userlevel='3'">
                    <div class="org bold">Organiser</div>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <div class="name adm bold">Administrator</div>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@id" mode="festid">
        <div class="heading2 bold"><h2>FESTIVAL ID: <xsl:value-of select="." /></h2></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="eventname">
        <div class="small bold">EVENT NAME:</div> 
        <div class="large bold"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="url">
        <div class="small bold">URL:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datefrom">
        <div class="small bold">DATE FROM:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dateto">
        <div class="small bold">DATE TO:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="location">
        <div class="small bold">LOCATION:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="eventpostcode">
        <div class="small bold">POSTCODE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="coords/lat">
        <div class="small bold">LATITUDE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="coords/lng">
        <div class="small bold">LONGITUDE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="conname">
        <div class="small bold">NAME:</div> 
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="conaddress1">
        <div class="small bold">ADDRESS:</div> 
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="conaddress2">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(conaddress2)!=0">
            <div class="small bold"><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text></div>
            <div class="large">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="concity">
        <div class="small bold">CITY:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="concounty">
        <div class="small bold">COUNTY:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="conpostcode">
        <div class="small bold">POSTCODE:</div>
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="contact">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(contelephone)!=0">
        <div class="small bold">TELEPHONE:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:value-of select="contelephone/." />
        </div>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="string-length(conmobile)!=0">
        <div class="small bold">MOBILE:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:value-of select="conmobile/." />
        </div>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="string-length(fax)!=0">
        <div class="small bold">FAX:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:value-of select="fax/." />
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="conemail">
        <div class="small bold">EMAIL:</div>
        <div class="large">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:text>mailto:</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a section of my xml.  If you need me to edit my post so you can see the full code I will but the rest works fine.

```
<folktask>
 <member>
  <user id="4">
   <personal>
    <name>Connor Lawson</name>
    <sex>Male</sex>
    <address1>12 Ash Way</address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <city>Swindon</city>
    <county>Wiltshire</county>
    <postcode>SN3  6GS</postcode>
    <telephone>01791928119</telephone>
    <mobile>07338695664</mobile>
    <email>itunestinker@fsmail.co.uk</email>
   </personal>
   <account>
    <username>iTuneStinker</username>
    <password>3a1f5fda21a07bfff20c41272bae7192</password>
    <userlevel>3</userlevel>
    <signupdate>2010-03-26T09:23:50</signupdate>
   </account>
  </user>
  <festival id="1">
   <event>
    <eventname>Oxford Folk Festival</eventname>
    <url>http://www.oxfordfolkfestival.com/</url>
    <datefrom>2010-04-07</datefrom>
    <dateto>2010-04-09</dateto>
    <location>Oxford</location>
    <eventpostcode>OX1 9BE</eventpostcode>
    <coords>
     <lat>51.735640</lat>
     <lng>-1.276136</lng>
    </coords>
   </event>
   <contact>
    <conname>Stuart Vincent</conname>
    <conaddress1>P.O. Box 642</conaddress1>
    <conaddress2></conaddress2>
    <concity>Oxford</concity>
    <concounty>Bedfordshire</concounty>
    <conpostcode>OX1 3BY</conpostcode>
    <contelephone>01865 79073</contelephone>
    <conmobile></conmobile>
    <fax></fax>
    <conemail>stewards@oxfordfolkfestival.com</conemail>
   </contact>
  </festival>
 </member>
</folktask>
```

Comment: You haven't provided the XSLT code with the Main problem. As for `<xsl:sort>`, it can only be a child (immediate!)of `<xsl:apply-templates>` or `<xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Edited post to show the whole code for the XSL stylesheet

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can sort the elements when you apply a template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="folktask/member">
  <xsl:sort select="festival/event/datefrom"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

You're also confusing your node context slightly:

```
<xsl:template match="conaddress2">
  <xsl:if test="string-length(conaddress2)!=0">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Should probably be:

```
<xsl:template match="conaddress2">
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.)!=0">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Since you're matching `conaddress2` the context node is set to conaddress2. If you try and use `string-length(conaddress2)` from this context it means you're trying to find a `conaddress2` child node of the current context node (which is `conaddress2`). In other words you're trying to find the length of `conaddress2\conaddress2`.

Similarly in this template:

```
<xsl:template match="contact">
  <xsl:if test="string-length(contelephone)!=0">
    <div class="small bold">TELEPHONE:</div>
    <div class="large">
      <xsl:value-of select="contelephone/." />
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="string-length(conmobile)!=0">
    <div class="small bold">MOBILE:</div>
    <div class="large">
      <xsl:value-of select="conmobile/." />
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="string-length(fax)!=0">
    <div class="small bold">FAX:</div>
    <div class="large">
      <xsl:value-of select="fax/." />
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You can remove the **"/."** from your select expressions. So instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="contelephone/." />
```

You can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="contelephone" />
```

(Although both worked the same in my XSLT parser.)